# jest-puppeteer: Access IndexedDB from window

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer, e2e-testing, jest-puppeteer

I'm trying to access indexedDB from the window object, however I keep getting the below error.

`DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'IDBFactory': access to the Indexed Database API is denied in this context.`

This is how I am trying to do it.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    const idb = window.indexedDB.open("databaseName");
});
```

I also set `--allow-file-access-from-files` as part of the args in the `jest-puppeteer.config.js` and set the `browserContext: 'default'`

Still I cannot get it to work! Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: how do you load your page initially? by running a server and `page.goto` or directly setting content with `page.setContent`?

Comment: I use `page.goto`